# Issue with for my Python LOOP not printing the PORT number correctly

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code and results below. The loop `p in range (0,10)` should result in my port being 1000-1009 in order and being attached to my `send()` as the source port, but as you can see from the results it only prints 9. I need it to loop through and print 1000-1009 for each 10 of my send().

```
from scapy.all import *

for i in xrange(10):    
    srcIP="172.16.16."+str(random.randint(1,254))
    port = '100'
    for p in range(0,10): value=port+str(p)
    ipFlags=0 if((i+1)%5) else 4
    tcpFlags='S' if(i<5) else 'UF'
    payload='bad' if(i+1)%2 else 'good'
    ip=IP(src=srcIP, flags=ipFlags, ttl=160, dst=['192.168.5.5'])
    tcp=TCP(sport=int(value), dport=80, flags=tcpFlags)
    send(ip/tcp/payload)
```

Here are the results that I am getting.  The port is always showing as 9.  I assume I just have my for loop in the wrong place, but can't figure it out.

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
223 595.843314  172.16.16.57    192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
224 595.879848  172.16.16.204   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
225 595.922197  172.16.16.125   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
226 595.970400  172.16.16.131   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
227 596.029877  172.16.16.203   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
228 596.083802  172.16.16.104   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
229 596.135179  172.16.16.163   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
230 596.176365  172.16.16.247   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
231 596.211904  172.16.16.129   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
232 596.268200  172.16.16.175   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
```

BELOW ARE THE RESULTS THAT I WANT/NEED

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
223 595.843314  172.16.16.57    192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1000 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
224 595.879848  172.16.16.204   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1001 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
225 595.922197  172.16.16.125   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1002 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
226 595.970400  172.16.16.131   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1003 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
227 596.029877  172.16.16.203   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
228 596.083802  172.16.16.104   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1005 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
229 596.135179  172.16.16.163   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1006 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
230 596.176365  172.16.16.247   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1007 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
231 596.211904  172.16.16.129   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1008 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=3 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
232 596.268200  172.16.16.175   192.168.5.5 TCP 60  1009 → 80 [FIN, URG] Seq=1 Win=8192 Urg=0 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regenerate the ports like the following:

```
port = 1000
for i in xrange(10):    
    srcIP="172.16.16."+str(random.randint(1,254))
    ipFlags=0 if((i+1)%5) else 4
    tcpFlags='S' if(i<5) else 'UF'
    payload='bad' if(i+1)%2 else 'good'
    ip=IP(src=srcIP, flags=ipFlags, ttl=160, dst=['192.168.5.5'])
    tcp=TCP(sport=port, dport=80, flags=tcpFlags)
    send(ip/tcp/payload)
    port += 1
```